# OOP in Nodejs. Nesting Classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to create a class for each nfl team.  in my code below you can see I create two https requests to an external API.  the first request creates a class for each NFL team and has various standing data, the second request then creates two different class objects for each team.  One for offensive stats and one for defensive stats.

My desired result is to have the offensive stats class and defensive stats class be appended onto the Nfl_team class based off of it matching the Team property. So instead of returning three different classes for each team it should be one class for each nfl team, with two sub-classes for the offensive and defensive stats. Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction?!  I'm totally lost on how to even do this and can't find anything online, maybe I just don't know what to look for.  Any help would be great.

**You can find the api key in the comments**

### get_teams.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Nfl_team from '../models/teamModel.js';
import Offensive_stats from '../models/offensiveStatsModel.js'
import Defensive_stats from '../models/defensiveStatsModel.js';
import colors from 'colors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();


let team = {};

axios.all([
        axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/fantasy/json/Standings/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`),
        axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/odds/json/TeamSeasonStats/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`)
    ])
    .then(function (responseArr) {

        /* Create a for each loop that goes over each obj and returns a new team object using NFL 
         team model with updated stats from sportsdata.io 
       __________________________________________________________________________________________*/

        responseArr[0].data.forEach(element => {

            let team = {
                [element.Team]: new Nfl_team(element.Team, element.Name, element.Wins, element.Losses, element.Ties,
                    element.Percentage, element.DivisionWins, element.DivisionLosses, element.DivisionTies,
                    element.PointsFor, element.PointsAgainst)
            }

            // console.log(`Model for ${element.Name}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(team);

            

        })

        responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {

            let offensive_stats = new Offensive_stats(element.Team, element.Touchdowns, element.RushingYardsPerAttempt,
                element.PassingYardsPerAttempt, element.CompletionPercentage, element.PasserRating, element.TimesSacked,
                element.QuarterbackHits, element.OffensivePlays);

            // console.log(`Offensive Stats Model for ${element.Team}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(offensive_stats);
            // console.log(`qb hit percentage = ${offensive_stats.quarterback_hits_percentage}`.bold.brightRed);

            console.log(team);
        })

        responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {

            let defensive_stats = new Defensive_stats(element.Team, element.OpponentTouchdowns, element.OpponentRushingYardsPerAttempt,
                element.OpponentPassingYardsPerAttempt, element.OpponentCompletionPercentage, element.OpponentPasserRating, element.OpponentTimesSacked,
                element.OpponentQuarterbackHits, element.OpponentOffensivePlays);

            // console.log(`Defensive Stats Model for ${element.Team}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(defensive_stats);
            // console.log(`opponent qb hit percentage = ${defensive_stats.opponent_quarterback_hits_percentage}`.bold.brightRed);
        })

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
```

### team_model.js

```
export default class Nfl_team {
    constructor(team=String, name=String, wins=Number, losses=Number, ties=Number, win_percentage=Number,
         division_wins=Number, division_losses=Number, division_ties=Number, points_for=Number, points_against=Number, offensive_stats, defensive_stats) {
        this.team = team;
        this.name = name;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        this.ties = ties;
        this.win_percentage = win_percentage;
        this.division_wins = division_wins;
        this.division_losses = division_losses;
        this.division_ties = division_ties;
        this.points_for = points_for;
        this.points_against = points_against;
        this.offensive_stats = {};
        this.defensive_stats = {};
    }

    get record() {
        return [this.wins,this.losses,this.ties];
    }

    get division_record() {
        return [this.division_wins, this.division_losses, this.division_ties];
    }
}
```

### offensive_stat_model.js

```
export default class Offensive_stats {

    constructor (team, touchdowns, rushing_yards_per_attempt, passing_yards_per_attempt, completion_percentage, passer_rating, 
   times_sacked, quarterback_hits, offensive_plays) {
        this.team = team;
        this.touchdowns = touchdowns;
        this.rushing_yards_per_attempt = rushing_yards_per_attempt;
        this.passing_yards_per_attempt = passing_yards_per_attempt;
        this.completion_percentage = completion_percentage;
        this.passer_rating = passer_rating;
        this.times_sacked = times_sacked;
        this.quarterback_hits = quarterback_hits;
        this.offensive_plays = offensive_plays;
    }

    get quarterback_hits_percentage() {
        return this.offensive_plays / this.quarterback_hits;
    }
}
```

### defensive_stat_model.js

```
export default class Defensive_stats {

    constructor (team, opponent_touchdowns, opponent_rushing_yards_per_attempt, oppenent_passing_yards_per_attempt, opponent_completion_percentage,
    opponent_passer_rating, opponent_times_sacked, opponent_quarterback_hits, opponent_offensive_plays) {
        this.team = team;
        this.opponent_touchdowns = opponent_touchdowns;
        this.opponent_rushing_yards_per_attempt = opponent_rushing_yards_per_attempt;
        this.oppenent_passing_yards_per_attempt = oppenent_passing_yards_per_attempt;
        this.opponent_completion_percentage = opponent_completion_percentage;
        this.opponent_passer_rating = opponent_passer_rating;
        this.opponent_times_sacked = opponent_times_sacked;
        this.opponent_quarterback_hits = opponent_quarterback_hits;
        this.opponent_offensive_plays = this.opponent_offensive_plays;
    }

    get opponent_quarterback_hits_percentage() {
        return this.opponent_offensive_plays / this.opponent_quarterback_hits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

Modify the `team` model to include placeholders for `offStats` and `defStats` - or something, then:

1. Collect the teams into an object literal `teams` like this:

`{ [element.Team] : team } // {Ravens : Nfl_team_object}`

2. While looping over the stats, in each loop do:

`teams[element.Team].offStats = new Offensive_stats(...)`

`teams[element.Team].defStats = new Defensive_stats(...)`

Or, using your existing code:

`teams[element.Team].offStats = offensive_stats;`

Each team will be *composed* of the team meta-data plus both related off/def stats objects.

Here is the code:

```js
axios.all([
    axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/fantasy/json/Standings/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`),
    axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/odds/json/TeamSeasonStats/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`)
  ])
  .then(function(responseArr) {
    responseArr[0].data.forEach(element => {
      teams[element.Team] = new Nfl_team(element.Team, element.Name, element.Wins, element.Losses, element.Ties,
        element.Percentage, element.DivisionWins, element.DivisionLosses, element.DivisionTies,
        element.PointsFor, element.PointsAgainst)
    });

    responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {
      teams[element.Team]['offensive_stats'] = new Offensive_stats(element.Team, element.Touchdowns, element.RushingYardsPerAttempt,
        element.PassingYardsPerAttempt, element.CompletionPercentage, element.PasserRating, element.TimesSacked,
        element.QuarterbackHits, element.OffensivePlays);
    });

    responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {
      teams[element.Team]['defensive_stats'] = new Defensive_stats(element.Team, element.OpponentTouchdowns, element.OpponentRushingYardsPerAttempt,
        element.OpponentPassingYardsPerAttempt, element.OpponentCompletionPercentage, element.OpponentPasserRating, element.OpponentTimesSacked,
        element.OpponentQuarterbackHits, element.OpponentOffensivePlays);
    });
    console.log(teams);

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: the team object is outside of the scope of the second loop though.  I am making two seperate calls to the api.

Comment: right, create the teams variable outside the first axios call. then, it is available inside the entire structure of nested `.then()` calls.

Comment: To be clear, create teams like this: `const teams = {}`;

Comment: When i do that, and then console.log(team) in the second foreach loop I get 32 blank objects.  they dont have the team data populated in them from the first one.  I got your first step from your first comment working but cannot get teams array to be inside second loop.

Comment: Put this up on stackblitz or repl.io or someplace with some mock data. I can't guess at what you're doing, but I can certainly make it work given the starter code you have above.

Comment: my api key is a3f7c417d6514314b0bd71fbb234f97c.  I changed the get_teams.js file.  I am now using axios.all instead of axios.get but am still getting the same issue.  Please look at the new code I posted if you can!

Comment: https://repl.it/join/tqsvwrrx-jordanvera1 here is the repl link.  Run npm run get_teams

Comment: Please see the updated answer and REPL https://repl.it/@JordanVera1/nflModel#index.js

Comment: can you take a look at the updated Repl code?  I changed the teams object to an array so I can perform array functions on it but now I cannot seam to get the matching offensive and defensive stats to the corresponding team...... Again, you are the man.

Comment: updated - from this point forward you'll need to ask for help in a new question. That way you'll get an answer if I'm unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

was a scope issue.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Nfl_team from '../models/teamModel.js';
import Offensive_stats from '../models/offensiveStatsModel.js'
import Defensive_stats from '../models/defensiveStatsModel.js';
import colors from 'colors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();


let team = {};

axios.all([
        axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/fantasy/json/Standings/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`),
        axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/api/nfl/odds/json/TeamSeasonStats/2019?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`)
    ])
    .then(function (responseArr) {

        /* Create a for each loop that goes over each obj and returns a new team object using NFL 
         team model with updated stats from sportsdata.io 
       __________________________________________________________________________________________*/

        responseArr[0].data.forEach(element => {

            team = {
                [element.Team]: new Nfl_team(element.Team, element.Name, element.Wins, element.Losses, element.Ties,
                    element.Percentage, element.DivisionWins, element.DivisionLosses, element.DivisionTies,
                    element.PointsFor, element.PointsAgainst)
            }

            // console.log(`Model for ${element.Name}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(team);

            

        })

        responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {

            let offensive_stats = new Offensive_stats(element.Team, element.Touchdowns, element.RushingYardsPerAttempt,
                element.PassingYardsPerAttempt, element.CompletionPercentage, element.PasserRating, element.TimesSacked,
                element.QuarterbackHits, element.OffensivePlays);

            // console.log(`Offensive Stats Model for ${element.Team}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(offensive_stats);
            // console.log(`qb hit percentage = ${offensive_stats.quarterback_hits_percentage}`.bold.brightRed);

            team.offensive_stats = offensive_stats;

            console.log(team);
        })

        responseArr[1].data.forEach(element => {

            let defensive_stats = new Defensive_stats(element.Team, element.OpponentTouchdowns, element.OpponentRushingYardsPerAttempt,
                element.OpponentPassingYardsPerAttempt, element.OpponentCompletionPercentage, element.OpponentPasserRating, element.OpponentTimesSacked,
                element.OpponentQuarterbackHits, element.OpponentOffensivePlays);

            // console.log(`Defensive Stats Model for ${element.Team}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            // console.log(defensive_stats);
            // console.log(`opponent qb hit percentage = ${defensive_stats.opponent_quarterback_hits_percentage}`.bold.brightRed);
        })

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
```